# Не работает навигация в landscape режиме

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap, responsive

Добрый день. не открывается меню в landscape режиме на экранах ipad. в портретном все ок. не знаю в чем причина. Ниже указал ссылку на пример такой проблемы в template. заранее спасибо
[ссылка на сайт пример](http://okthemes.com/villenoir/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот `media-запрос` отвечает за показ меню. Поэтому на `landscape` не открывается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Но не могли бы вы подсказать как решить такого рода проблему?

Comment: изменить `max-width` в `@media`

Comment: Огромное спасибо